# Получение списка новостей из группы в Вконтакте

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Я очень зеленый программер. Пытаюсь получить тексты новостей из определенной группы, но получаю одно и то же

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int appId = 477777;
    string email = "Моя учетка";
    string password = "Мой пароль";
    Settings settings = Settings.All;
    var api = new VkApi();
    api.Authorize(appId, email, password, settings);
    var group = api.Utils.ResolveScreenName("etorostov");
    long id = group.Id.Value;
    int totalCount;
    int count = 5;
    int offset = 0;
    var wallpost = api.Wall.Get(id, out totalCount, count, offset, WallFilter.All);
    foreach (var one in wallpost)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(one.Text);
    }
}
```

В итоге я получаю в дебаге одни и те же новости (и больше ничего) и они не добавляются в листбокс. Помогите, господа!

Answer (score 1):

Нашел причину.

```
var wallpost = api.Wall.Get(id, out totalCount, count, offset, WallFilter.All);
```

в этой строчке перед id нужно поставить минус, чтобы новости выгребались именно с группы.